using react v18 with Typescript < v5.1, while allowing string as valid JSX Element
Full reproducible repo is https://github.com/Liooo/vite-project, just run yarn install && yarn tsc to see the error.
I want to use react v18 with Typescript < v5.1, but tsc raises error TS2786  'MyComponent' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'string' is not a valid JSX element. like below:
const MyComponent = () => 'x'

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <MyComponent />
    　　 // ↑
        // error TS2786: 'MyComponent' cannot be used as a JSX component.
        //     Its return type 'string' is not a valid JSX element.
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

// package.json
{

  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.5" // <= the error disappears with for example "5.1.6"
  }
}

When I update typescript to > v5.1, the error disappears.
Tried tweaking JSX.Element augmentation like these but no luck so far.
to be precise, my goal here is the following:

use react@v18
use typescript@v4.9.5
allow string (and other ReactNode-ish types) as valid JSX Element

Notes:
Wrapping strings in elements like const MyComponent = () => (<>{'x'}</>) works, but don't wanna do this, wanna be able to return string from component)
The error should be related to this microsoft/Typescript issue

Have you tried returning a JSX fragment instead? return <>some string</>;

The reason it works in 5.1+ is probably due to Decoupled Type-Checking Between JSX Elements and JSX Tag Types in response to this issue

Does this answer your question? How to return string or JSX element in TypeScript React component?

Please also see Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?

@Phil yes, that works but that's not how it's supposed to be

I don't understand what you're asking. Yes, it was an issue in TypeScript. Yes, they've fixed it. As with any bug in older software, if you cannot upgrade you need a work-around

@Phil our old codebase breaks a lot when upgrading typescript,  the requirement is that using react v18, Typescript < v5.1, and allow string (and number and other ReactNode-ish types) to be valid as JSX.Element.
I thought module augmentation was the workaround to go, but not having luck with it

And I think the error cause is exactly related to this one https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/51328

"I'm looking for the workaround"... you've been presented with some in the suggested duplicate. Have you tried those? If so, how do they not satisfy your requirements?

@Phil none of those are the workaround I'm looking for, they suggest wrapping in component and not

The solution is not to use such on an old version of TS, how hard can it be to upgrade? Usually it's easy

Did you try return "mystring" as unknown as JSX.Element as per this answer? You haven't explained why you cannot wrap your string in a fragment either

that's essentially same as wrapping in <>{...}</>. as I said, I want the JSX.Element to accept string and other ReactNode types in the codebase, as it should be.

It's just not possible with the TypeScript version you're using and no, it's not even close to being the same thing. It's really unclear what sort of answer you're looking for here but it sounds like pure wishful thinking... "I want this specific version of TypeScript to do something it cannot without me making any changes"

@Dominic
we would be doing so if we could, but got a bunch of legacy codebase that viciously breaks after ts upgrade and decided not to do so right now, thus looking for a workaround :(

@Phil
as I said, the type of workaround I'm looking for is different, I guessed module augmentation could be the way, just like what TypeScript did at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/51328

There's no workaround except upgrading typescript:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/discussions/69919#discussioncomment-9892117

just run the function?
Why try to make functional component return a string?
const myStringfunc = (): string => { return 'x' }
...
<div>{ myStringfunc() }</div>

apparently I need to change function name to make it clear I'm not suggesting a FC as a solution but a regular function that returns a string. If the real use case resulted in a expensive re-render, hoist it, bind it to a const, memoize it.

it is not a component it is a static function in this example, I just kept the naming convention op used.

thanks, but my point is about allowing string to be rendered as JSX element throughout the whole codebase. The reason is because that's what original react behavior is, and want the type to work accordingly without wrapping all occurences in return <>{stringVar}</>, or return stringVar as unknown as ReactElement etc.

ok then like then accepted answer, there is no workaround other than upgrading TS
